# How to not apply a function when all parameters are given

Tags: scala

Give the following scenario:

```
def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
def f1(adder: () => Int) = adder()

f1(add(1,2) _) // Does **NOT** compile, because add seems to be already executed
f1(() => add(1,2)) // This works, but seems to be ugly
```

Is there any way to make it work with the underscore?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. Can you rephrase?

Comment: add(1,2) is an Int, not a function and you can't turn it back into one by adding a _. Defining a function that returns add(1,2) is needed, and that's exactly what your "ugly" solution does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make it work without the underscore by using a by-name parameter:

```
scala> def f2(adder: => Int) = adder
f2: (adder: => Int)Int

scala> f2(add(1,2))
res0: Int = 3
```

The problem with your 3rd line is that `f1` *needs* a function that is called with empty params. A by-name parameter lets you pass in any arbitrary expression that results in the given type, and doesn't evaluate it until you use it within the method body. If you want to use a by-name argument in multiple places within the body of the method, but don't want it reevaluated, you can cache it by assigning it to a `lazy val`.

Comment: Ahh thanks for you answer. I didn't recognize there is a difference between => and () =>. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @regexp Consider that both get translated to `Function0`. There is just some syntactic sugar for `=>`.